# How to ground antenna's current naturally?

Tags: circuit-design, ground

I built a RF detector circuit as seen below.

It works approximately in a range of three meters efficiently.

The LED at top of antenna will light when I am about 20 cm from a 2.4 GHz router modem. When the distance is bigger, it flashes but the blue LED at the bottom will still give light because this one has been amplified with a battery.

The problem I had at the beginning was, why this circuit was not working. After experimenting I have found out that it must be grounded somehow. I touched one of the antennas with my finger and it worked as expected. My question is about how to ground the antenna naturally without touching them with a finger, for example.

[image]

As the answer below, I was looking for a balanced dipole antenna and I found out an image on the internet. I think making coils ready for the dipole antenna will make the earth mechanism for real.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clear things up, we call it earth (not ground) and your finger is capacitively coupled to earth via your body. If you call it ground, it could mean 0 volts (a simple node name) but it doesn't explicitly make it "earth". So, I'm referring to earth in my answer.

> *My question is about how to ground the antenna naturally without
> touching them with finger*

It uses a dipole antenna (on the face of it) and therefore it shouldn't need an earth. But, you are not operating it as a dipole because of the way it is connected. The way it is connected is as a monopole and that does need earth to make it work effectively.

However, you are not really using it as a monopole either because of the way you have diodes on the dipole feeds and a single node connection to your transistor. In other words, somebody has tried to concoct some kind of receiver and, got it wrong in a couple of places but, convinced themselves it worked as they expected when, it doesn't really do that.

But, it does work as an effective electric field receiver and, that's what you are seeing and, an effective electric field receiver will definitely benefit from an earth connection.

If you want it to work (as you might of originally expected) you have to make a balanced dipole receiver. Or just live with the fact that it is an electric field receiver and, not a radio (electromagnetic wave) receiver.

Comment: Thank you. I will look after making a balanced dipole receiver.

Comment: I have still one question. When i remove the diodes and the led at the top and keep a little space between the antennas, will the circuit work then? I mean changing the antenna from monopole to dipole without all rectifiers, will this take effect? I will solder these things together and let the parts out as referred above.

Comment: It is now evening and i will try on it harder another time.

Comment: I do not think that i will have to remove the parts, like diodes and the led at the top. I can solder the antenna, left or right one, to a copper plate or similar that kind. It will work to ground it. So, the antenna will go on to serve as monopole antenna.

Comment: I will tell you later more about this project.

Comment: You need the antenna to operate as a dipole antenna. Only then can you avoid needing an earth connection.

Comment: Well, i tried out an old tv dipole antenna and i can confirm that it works without external earthing this time.

Comment: @dude yeah using a balun (balanced to unbalanced transformer) is a good way to make this work.